# CkEditor Preenche dados na URL ao fazer envio

Tags: php, javascript, html, ckeditor

Bom dia galera.

Já viram esse problema ao usar o Ckeditor?

Eu tenho um formulário onde a minha caixa de texto `<textarea></textarea>` é substituido pelo editor de texto Ckeditor.

Eu tenho isso na minha página:

```
<form class="panel input-group col-md-12" id="form_relatorio">
                    <textarea id="texto_relatorio" name="texto_relatorio" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite nesse espaço o Relatório de Serviço"></textarea>

                    <script>
                            CKEDITOR.replace( 'texto_relatorio', {  enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR, shiftEnterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR } );
                             CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev )
                            {
                             ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'br',
                             {
                                indent : false,
                                breakBeforeOpen : false,
                                breakAfterOpen : false,
                                breakBeforeClose : false,
                                breakAfterClose : false
                             });
                        });

                    </script>
                    <div class="form-group row" >
                        <label for="data_relatorio" class="col-xs-3 col-form-label">Data do Chamado: </label>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <input class="form-control" type="date" id="data_relatorio" name="data_relatorio" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>              
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="empresas" class="col-xs-3">Serviço Prestado à:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <select class="form-control" type="search" name="empresas" id="empresas">    
                                <option value="Avulso">Avulso</option>                          
                                <option value="cliente1">Cliente 1</option>
                                <option value="cliente2">Cliente 2</option>
                                <option value="cliente3">Cliente 3</option>                                                         
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="btn_relatorio" type="submit">Enviar</button>                          

                </form>
```

E no começo da minha página no meu arquivo header.php tenho o envio do form e a abertura do Ckeditor:

```
$('#btn_relatorio').click( function(){

        for(var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances)
        CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].updateElement();


        if($('#texto_relatorio').val(). length > 0){                
            $.ajax({
                url: 'inc/envia_relatorio.php',
                method: 'post',
                data: $('#form_relatorio').serialize(),
                sucess: function(data){                     
                    $('#texto_relatorio').val('');
                        atualizaRelatorio();
                        return false;                           
                }
            });
        }               

    });
```

Ele está fazendo tudo direitinho. Enviando pro meu Banco de Dados, com a formatação tudo correta. Meu problema é que sempre que dou o submit no formulário, todas minhas variáveis vão pra URL, ficando gigante um exemplo ela fica assim:
`http://local.mentec.com.br/sistema/relatorios?texto_relatorio=teste&data_relatorio=2017-11-05&empresas=Avulso`

Como se eu simplesmente enviasse por GET.
Acredito que esses dados que estão indo são do `textarea` antes do Ckeditor.
Existe alguma maneira de "barrar" esse texto de ir pra URL?

Pois se eu enviar uns 2 ou 3 formulários em seguida, já recebo erro de uma URL muito extensa do meu servidor e não me deixa enviar os dados, ai preciso ficar recarregando a página ou limpar a URL.

Valeu galera, abraços

Answer (score 0):

Ah deixa quieto galera, descobri uma função que  dá pra usar no próprio CKEditor, o SetData('').

Ficando assim:

```
$('#btn_relatorio').click( function(){

        for(var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances)
        CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].updateElement();
        CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].setData('');


        if($('#texto_relatorio').val(). length > 0){                
            $.ajax({
                url: 'inc/envia_relatorio.php',
                method: 'post',
                data: $('#form_relatorio').serialize(),
                sucess: function(data){                     
                    $('#texto_relatorio').val('');
                        atualizaRelatorio();
                        return false;                           
                }
            });
        }   return false;           

    });
```

Dessa eu substituo o meu Button type de submit para `type="button"`
E acrescento um `return false;` no final do meu IF para limpar o campo e não fazer o submit via URL.

Valeu O7